# how to get current route name in blade file laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, pageload

I want to reload my current page with onclick function, for this how to get my current route name in blade file.

This is my code:

```
<li class="dropdown user user-menu" onclick="window.location='{{ Route::current() }}'" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="livicon" data-name="refresh" data-loop="true" data-color="#42aaca" 
        data-hovercolor="#42aaca" data-size="28"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

What is the best way to get the current route?

I want to use it on function `onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload current page like this:

```
onclick="window.location.reload()"
```

There is no need to set current route in blade it's possible with javascript abilities.

Answer (score 3):

With Below code you can know more about your current route.

> $route = Route::current();
>
> $name = Route::currentRouteName();
>
> $action = Route::currentRouteAction();

Reference : [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for this for a long time. Couldn't find it in docs on api guide

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get current url in Laravel blade:

```
onclick="window.location='{{ Request::url() }}'"
```